# SpringFox - Is there a way to substitute the model specification/definition where ResponseEntity<?> is used for an actual class?

Tags: springfox

We're using these versions of SpringFox:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
             <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
             <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-spring-web</artifactId>
             <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And instantiate SpringFox/Swagger 2 using the below bean:

```
@Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .alternateTypeRules(
          AlternateTypeRules.newRule(typeResolver.resolve(ResponseEntity.class, WildcardType.class),
                        typeResolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)))
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }
```

We are using ResponseEntity generic for the return type:

```
@RequestMapping(value = “/someMethod”, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> someMethod(@RequestBody Application app) {

        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(aService.someMethod(app), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String errorMessage = ex + " <== error";
            LOG.error(errorMessage, ex);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Using ResponseEntity we are getting empty model schema {} when we try to view the response model Schema using swagger-ui.html. If we change the return type to ResponseEntity the model schema is populated for the response.

We were wondering if there is a way using an annotation, or some configuration to substitute the model specification/definition where ResponseEntity is used for an actual class?

Thanks!

Comment: `Using ResponseEntity we are getting empty model schema {} [..] If we change the return type to ResponseEntity the model schema is populated for the response.` It works with ResponseEntity but it doesn't? Could you elaborate this?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add the object in my question above. What I meant was "If we change the return type to ResponseEntity<SomeObject> the model schema is populated for the response."                              
    public ResponseEntity<SomeObject> someMethod(@RequestBody Application app) {...}